# Html 5 run two of the same scripts

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have a javascript file which handles a chart from chartjs. I want to have multiple charts with this javascript file to handle them. Something like this:

```html
<!--Chart One-->
<script src="timeChart.js" name="chart2"></script>
<script>    document.getElementById('AddData').addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
            chartData = (Math.round(Math.random() * 100) - 50);
        });
</script>

<!--Chart One-->
<script src="timeChart.js" name="chart2"></script>
<script>
        document.getElementById('AddData2').addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
            chartData = (Math.round(Math.random() * 100) - 50);
        });
    </script>
```

And also I cannot go through a for loop of these charts to handle them because I need to set variables inside them outside of that script.

Comment: Use `document.getElementByClassName()` instead maybe?

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: So, I have multiple charts that I need on my html page and on these charts it needs graph a variable over time. To do this I have created a javascript file in which you set the name of the html element and can set its variable. This system works great for one graph but wont work for mutliple graphs. I want to figure out how to use this system for multiple graphs.

Comment: If there was a way to plug in a reference variable for a script that work would great.

Comment: and btw the code under "Chart One" works by itself but does not work if "Chart Two" is there also.